# Changing specific class in default.ctp

Tags: cakephp, layout

Below is my `default.ctp` file. My question was how do I change 
  `class="post-content"` from another view or page?

```
   <main class="main-content">
          <div class="post-content"> 
            <?php echo $this->Session->flash(); ?>
            <?php echo $this->fetch('content'); ?>  
          </div>            
   </main>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your layout, you can change the static class to include a simple if/else statement shown below:

```
<main class="main-content">
    <div class="<?php echo (isset($layout_class_var)) ? $layout_class_var : 'post-content'; ?>"> 
        <?php echo $this->Session->flash(); ?>
        <?php echo $this->fetch('content'); ?>  
    </div>            
</main>
```

Then each time you want to set a new class name in place of the default class **post-content**, just set the desired class name into the **$layout_class_var** variable in your controller action:

```
public function someAction() {
    //set layout class to 'new-layout-class'
    $this->set('layout_class_var', 'new-layout-class');
}
```